# What does it mean to detrend a time series at a given rate?

Tags: macroeconomics, business-cycles

What does it mean to detrend a time series at a given rate, say, 1.5%?

[image]

[image]

What is the formula here? $X_t - trend$? where trend = average growth rate? Say $X_t - 0.015$?

Comment: Your understanding of the formula is correct, if I am not mistaken. Probably more relevantly however is the process of estimating the trend such as through the residuals.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that they detrended by computing the discounted value. (Although I'm not sure if this is really what they've done.)

Let $r = 0.015$ be the growth rate and let $t$ be the time period and $t_0$ the base year, (e.g. $t = 2000$ and $t_0 = 1982$).

If $Y_t$ is GDP in period $t$ then the detrended GDP is given by:
$$
\frac{Y_t}{(1+r)^{t-t_0}}.
$$

If you work in quarters, $t$ should also be transformed accordingly. For example, if the period is $2010Q1$, you should use $t = 2010.25$.